# Javascript: Insert link into Mouse right click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering how would I include my function on my website inside a users right click? for example function `hello()` with Title `Hello` is an option when a user right clicks on my website.

**edit:** I simply wish to append to the current right click menu. Not make my own.

Comment: AFAIK browsers don't support modification of the context menu as of yet.

Comment: Most browsers do support it - Umbraco uses context menus all over their administration interface. But you will have to trap the right mouse click and write your own context menu code from scratch.

Comment: It's usually not a good idea to change the way your users' browsers behave. If people right-click and don't get their expected menu, they may be turned off to your site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the answer to this is it can't be done, as right-click context menus are controlled by the browser. However, there's cool stuff like this around: http://luke.breuer.com/tutorial/javascript-context-menu-tutorial.htm .

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this.

```
$('div').mousedown(function(event) {
    switch (event.which) {
        case 1:
            alert('Mouse left click');
            break;
        case 2:
            alert('Mouse middle click');
            break;
        case 3:
            alert('Mouse right click');
            break;
        default:
            alert('Do something else');
    }
});
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/2AqnW/